# Giving full trust to a site in a medium trust host

Tags: iis-6, windows-server-2003

I have admin access to a Windows 2003 server. The trust level is set to medium trust with allowOverride=false.

I was wondering if there's a way to add an exception in the configuration files so that one site can run in full trust. By using the location tag?

What if the AppPool has an identity in the admin group or the medium trust trumps that?

For PremissonSet and IPermission, can these be used to set custom permissions for a certain site only or are they server wide settings only? I don't other sites to inherit these permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sites which need full trust are added in the machine.config file.

Comment: where would one find the machine.config file?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but this is a terrible idea. If you have code that you must do in full trust, then write a service which does just that function, and have your (non-full-trust) web application query the service. The idea of putting a full trust web application up on the Internet (or even the intranet) is, frankly, frightening. Better, of course, would be to remove the full trust requirement, if possible, but of course you can't always do that.

Comment: The site could be using third party components which need full trust. I don't have control over them. Maybe a solution is to write a wrapper around them but I haven't try it and know it works.

It's an issue only if you don't trust your own site's security. I wonder how some hosters run full trust.